# Using Android Id's?

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

I am still trying to figure out frame animation, but I need to use IDs. I get these errors:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:oneshot="false" android:id="@+id/carrotsmileanim"> 
<item android:drawable="@drawable/carrotsmile" android:duration="2000" /> 
<item android:drawable="@drawable/carrotblink" android:duration="2000" /> 
<android:id="@+id/carrotsmileanim></android:id>
</animation-list>
```

In the ID section the error is: "

```
android:id" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>"
```

My code:

```
package com.example.carrottest2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.R;

public class Carrottest2 extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

AnimationDrawable mainanimation; 

public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {  
     super.onCreate(icicle);  

     ImageView carrotsmile = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.carrotblink);
     rocketImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rocket_thrust);
     c = (AnimationDrawable) rocketImage.getBackground();
     carrotsmileanim.start();
```

The tutorial frame animation android IDs are still there, I never changed them, but it does not recognize these, and it gives me a "cannot be resolved or is not a field." error.

Which is supposed to go where?

Is main.xml involved in this? I know there is supposed to be an imageview somewhere, but I'm not sure where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matt Huggins is right. What you've posted isn't valid XML because of the missing quotation mark. But also, I don't think 'id' is a tag that is used by android. It's an attribute (as you used it, correctly, on the root element) but AFAIK there is no `<android:id>` element. When you add the `id` attribute to something, it automatically creates that id, and makes it accessible via your generated `R` file.

Comment: I realize, but id should be next to imageview and findviewbyid, setbackgroundesource, animationdrawable, getbackground, and start? Also, eclipse will not recognize the second quotation! Why is this?

Comment: I'm not sure what your comment is about. What do you mean Eclipse won't recognize your quotation mark?